# New web application and site not created through SharePoint Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint

I installed SharePoint Server 2007 trial version and SQL Server 2005 Express in my system. To create a new web application I did the following:

1. On the SharePoint Central Administration page, click the Application Management tab.
2. On the Application Management page, click the link titled Create or Extend 
   Web Application.
3. On the Create or Extend Web Application page, click the link titled Create a 
   New Web Application.
4. Fill the required field.

Then when I click the "OK" button no event fires on the click and there is no postback. No application is created but the cancel button is working fine.

Please help, I don't know why this is happening. Is it a limitation of the trial version or something else?

Comment: Please could you provide some more information. The trail version is not crippled with regards to creating sites, however there may have been an error which you are missing (normally at the top of the page after clicking create). The process wouldn't have come this far if it was configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Okay this is the usual Issue with the New Installation of the SharePoint , by default the Internet Explorer of Windows 2003 runs in the very restrictive mode (IE Enhanced Security Configuration Enabled), which also includes the JavaScript, so that the event not getting fired.To solve this Add the site as Trusted site in the IE and set the Security Level to Low. Close the Browser and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

Or even better, add it to the "Local Intranet" zone in Internet Explorer (tools -> internet options -> security tab, then select "Local Intranet" and click the sites button, then the Advanced button.)